# Is the symmetric closure of a relation which is already transitive, itself transitive?

Tags: relations

Let $R$ be a transitive relation. Is the symmetric closure of $R$ also transitive?

Comment: Go through the axioms.

Comment: $R = \{(a, b), (b,c)\}.$ Symmetric closure means $R^s = \{(a, b), (b, a),(b, c), (c, b\}$.  R is transitive., $R^s$ is not.  To be transitive, $R^s$ must include $(a, a), (b, b), (a, c)$ et al.

Comment: @amWhy In your example $R$ is not transitive, as it must also include $(a,c)$ to be transitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counterexample, adapted from @amWhy's attempt based on an observation by @aefrrs: if $a\ne b\ne c\ne a$, the transitive relation $\{(a,\,b),\,(b,\,c),\,(a,\,c)\}$ has symmetric closure $\{(a,\,b),\,(b,\,c),\,(a,\,c),\,(b,\,a),\,(c,\,b),\,(c,\,a)\}$, which isn't transitive as it doesn't own $\{a,\,a\}$. As @NoahSchweber notes, a simpler example, whose transitivity is [vacuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth), is $\{(a,\,b)\}$ with $a\ne b$.